# Cross-Origin Request Blocked with Sinatra and ReactJS

Tags: ruby, cors, sinatra

I am building a simple Sinatra backend with ReactJS frontend. When I try to make request to a route in my Sinatra project from React app it gives me CORS error. I tried to enable CORS in my project like this but it didn't work:

```rb
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/cross_origin'
require 'json'

configure do
    enable :cross_origin
end

set :allow_origin, :any
set :allow_methods, [:get, :post, :options]
set :allow_credentials, true
set :max_age, "1728000"
set :expose_headers, ['Content-Type']

get '/' do 
    'Hello!'    
end

post '/download' do
    content_type :json

    return {res: params['songs']}.to_json
end
```

So when I do a request like this from React:

```js
axios.post('http://localhost:4567/download', {}, {
    songs: this.state.songs
}).then(res => {
    console.log(res.data)
})
```

I get a CORS error which looks like this:
[image]

And I get this error in the console:
[image]

What should I change in my Sinatra/React project to make this work so I can make requests from React to Sinatra?

Comment: Try adding `before { response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*' }`

Comment: @maxpleaner still not working sadly

Comment: Are you sure it's a CORS error? I don't see the actual error in your question

Comment: @maxpleaner Oh sorry, I'll screenshot the error in the console. Let me update the question

Comment: @maxpleaner I updated the question

Comment: you restarted your server?

Comment: Yes I restarted it, I even tried to restart react app

Comment: Hard cache refresh?

Comment: Nope still not working. But now it's saying this `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4567/download' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.` does this mean anything to you?

Comment: No it doesn't but I would definitely Google that error and see if something comes up

Comment: "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)"
"[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)"
"[I downvoted because an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)"
"[I downvoted because an image of your exception isn't helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/britg/sinatra-cross_origin#responding-to-options. You need to add your own code to manually handle `OPTIONS` requests — because the `sinatra-cross_origin` gem itself doesn’t actually handle `OPTIONS` requests. Specifically, you’d need to add this:

```rb
options "*" do
  response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "HEAD,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS"
  response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "Content-Type"
  200
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact issue as you with Sinatra & React, after countless hours of searching I couldn't find any solution until I found this gem, https://github.com/jdesrosiers/sinatra-cors

Here's my solution which implements the basics:

```
require "sinatra/cors"

set :allow_origin, "*"
set :allow_methods, "GET,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
set :allow_headers, "X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Cache-Control, Accept, if-modified-since"
set :expose_headers, "location,link"
```